# Blender export to unity the mesh object dislocated

Tags: unity

I'm a new blender user, I've created a bird with rigifly and made 3 animations in blender (before rigifly, I've scaled and rotated both eyes and the bird body). However, after being exported to Unity, the eyes of the birds were dislocated.

I'm using Blender 2.93.6 and unity 2020.3.24f1.

Kindly advise the solution.[image]

Comment: Without knowing your model I can only advise you to check where the origins of the bird and the eyes are and compare that to the result in Unity. For example let's say the bird is at (1, 1, 2) and one eye is parented to the bird with **local** coordinates (0.5, 0, 1), than they are **globally** (1+0.5, 1+0, 2+1) = (1.5, 1, 3). And maybe Unity takes the **local** coordinates as **global** ones and puts the eye at (0.5, 0, 1) globally, then it's of course dislocated. That's just a guess, not sure how Unity places the objects. Another thing to check is if the scale is applied on all objects.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your advice. Would you please advise how to set the coordinate of the bird and eyes? I've applied scale and rotation to all three objects, so all objects are located at x0, y0, z0.

Please find the above screen capture. Btw, how can I share the blender file here?

Comment: I'm sorry, without knowing the model or Unity... I'm just trying to solve in Blender here, I'm not using Unity and have no idea how it places objects in a scene. I also have no idea how Unity treats rigs etc.